# Shell script to multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Please tell me where I'm going wrong. I'm trying to assign the output of a shell script to an array in php. I've done a lot of searching but don't know what I'm searching for.  :(

```
// Run the command line script...
$myArray = shell_exec($cmd);

// "echo $myArray" returns something like this...
// array('example','example two',array('another level',array('level three')));

echo recursive_array($myArray);
// Returns this...
// Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 

// Recursive array function
function recursive_array($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            recursive($value);
        } else {
            echo $key.' = '.$value, '<br/>';
        }
    }
}

// If I copy the output and manually define the 
// array, the function seems to work as intended.
// $myArray = array('example','example two',array('another level', array('level three')));
```

Thanks guys, that seemed to do the trick! Here is my updated code...

```
$result = shell_exec($cmd);
eval('$myArray = '.$result);
$html = recursive_array($myArray);
echo $html;

// Recursive Array Function
function recursive_array($array)
{
    $content = '';
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            $content .= $key.'<br />'.recursive_array($value).'<br />';
        } else {
            $content .= $key.' = '.$value.'<br />';
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: You can use eval() to pass the shell command output as a string and create the array, but eval() is EVIL :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval()` is not always evil:

```
$result = shell_exec($cmd);
eval('$myArray = ' . $result);
print_r($myArray);
```

`shell_exec()` is returning a string representation of an array that you can assign as PHP to `$myArray` with `eval()`.